# Trigger a reminder if activity has not been recorded in x amount of time

Tags: civireport, activities, scheduled-reminders

Is there a way to have CiviCRM send me a scheduled reminder for any contact for whom I have not recorded an activity for in 3 weeks or more? So that if 3 weeks go by and I have not recorded an activity for Contact A, I would get an email notifying me of that. 
Or is there a way to build a report showing all the people who haven't had an activity recorded for in 3+ weeks?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a current capability, though it's one I've thought about writing on multiple occasions.  Unfortunately, my clients have never deemed it something worth the time it would take.

To handle this, I think it would be best to create a custom search that searched for the latest activity.  For other use cases, searching only for activities of a particular type is helpful, but it sounds like you don't need that.

Once you have a custom search, you can create a smart group based on it.  You can then run reports and/or generate scheduled reminders limited to this group.

Answer (score 2):

I think [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) can help you here, although you would have to develop your own condition. Luckily that would be pretty straightforward, check the [CiviRules developer documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-introduction/)